# Correct way of adding wow.js to symfony webpack encore

Tags: symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore, wow.js

I'm using Symfony 4.3.3 with `webpack-encore-bundle` v1.6.2 to develop website. When trying to add `wow.js` to the front-end, I'm facing with this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
```

I ran `npm install --save wowjs` to install this package. Then import the library in the `app.js` as follow:

```
import WOW from 'wowjs/dist/wow.min.js';
```

After using `yarn encore dev` public files successfully created in output folder of `webpack`.

`new WOW().init();` in `main.js` file arises the above error.

So, What's the correct way of doing that or basically I must do more stuff to have this working?

Thanks

Comment: Quick and dirty is something like this, right after your import:
window.WOW = WOW;

Comment: Thanks, @Dimitris, I did it and now it says `wowjs_dist_wow_min_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a is not a constructor`

Comment: Something like: const WOW = require('wowjs'); window.wow = new WOW.WOW({ live: false });

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
import { WOW } from 'wowjs'
window.WOW = WOW;
```

Option 2:

```
window.WOW = require('wowjs').WOW;
```